# Python Dash: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Working with [Python Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) and have it working from local host, but when attempt to deploy to my python app server, I have issues.

When I keep the app as just Flask it works with this code:

```
from flask import Flask
import dash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
     return "Hello World!"
```

When I try to pass the server to the Dash instance (when according to Dash docs is acceptable, I receive the error).  Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask
import dash

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


 I receiving the error:

AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'route'
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Dash. Where in the docs does it say you can do this?

Comment: https://dash.plot.ly/deployment

Answer (score 4):

The docs don't say what you think they do. `app` is the Dash instance, not the Flask one - that is available via the `server` variable, so you can call `route` on that.

```
@server.route("/")
def hello():
     return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: I tried that exact thing as well, did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Roseman said, you must use `server.route` instead of `app.route`.

However, Dash registers itself to serve the path `/`, overwriting your route.

Other paths not used by Dash work as expected, e.g.:

```
@server.route('/hello-world')
def hello():
     return "Hello World!"
```